# How do I know when aspects are "hidden" from my players?

Tags: fate, fate-accelerated, aspects

Well, I'm quite new to Fate and today we had our very first session, we had a lot of fun but aspects confused us a lot.

I made the areas so my players would fight a Titan on the forests, one of the areas had a river on it and my player asked me if he could use his "Magical Tactician" aspect to freeze the river and make it slippery for the enemies, however, I told him in order to use the river he needed to use "Create an Advantage" to discover the aspect "River" and use it by spending a Fate Point. Wr discussed a bit about it but none of us understood the rules so well, and in the end we did as I said.

However this made me think how to handle aspects hidden from the players, such as how is someone supposed to know which aspect to uncover from the enemy or how is discovering an aspect better than creating your own... What am I missunderstanding here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do appear to be missing some stuff here. Here's how I'd handle your situation.

(As a foreword: bear in mind your *players* and the *player characters* being unaware of an aspect are two very different things, so you should make sure you distinguish between them.)

## Entering the Scene

You said you entered a Forest with a River in it. The forest itself is pretty important, and you should probably have an aspect on the scene describing the forest you're in. If you also know for a fact there's a river, and it just wasn't mechanically important enough to be an aspect until now, [you can just turn that fact into an aspect on the spot](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/using-aspects-roleplaying#creating-and-discovering-new-aspects-in-play) the moment anyone considers it important mechanically:

> If you’re not looking for a free invocation, and you just think it’d make sense if there were a particular situation aspect in play, you don’t need to roll the dice or anything to make new aspects—just suggest them, and if the group thinks they’re interesting, write them down.

(This doesn't take an action or anything.)

You could either explicitly mention there's a *Fording River*, or just consider it implied by the Forest aspect.

If there isn't a river in the forest, or there might be but nobody's sure yet, you don't need to have an aspect for it. Your players or your NPCs can "discover" it later.

## Creating the River

You would handle this very differently.

#### If there's a river aspect...

The characters might already know about it. It might even be a zone in the conflict! There's no need to "discover" it at all. People can begin using it immediately.

If the characters aren't yet aware of a River, it might not have even been significant enough to warrant creating an aspect for it. If it *was* that significant and they don't know about it, you're justified in asking them to try to discover it first. Normally you'd save this for bigger stuff, like the characters not yet being aware a recurring NPC is the *Vampire Lord* (but the players would probably know). This is just a small scene aspect.

#### If you didn't create a River aspect...

Your player can now Create an Advantage to "discover" the River, and create an aspect on the scene describing it. It was now retroactively there all along - but it only just became significant to the story. For the same reason, you might not worry about describing the small wildlife until someone throws nuts around and creates *Squirrels, Squirrels Everywhere!!* aspect.

This is your players' most powerful tool for just *making things be the case* in the world. Bear in mind: if they're in a desert, you'd be justified in making the discovery of a river a Fantastic (+6) challenge, or harder.

## Using the River

Your Magical Tactician is at this point aware of a River, one way or another.

Nobody needs to spend any Fate Points to do stuff involving the River. The very existence of an aspect describing one means one exists, and people can interact with it. (Previous versions of Fate might have required a Fate point to use it, but not Core or Accelerated Edition.)

Your players might want to *invoke* the river (especially if they have free invocations on it), but this isn't required.

Now that the river exists: the Magical Tactician can go ahead and use a regular Create an Advantage action to freeze it and make things slippery. That's it! They can just do that now.

Here's a couple of things they may want to do with that *Create an Advantage* action:

- Place a *Slippery Ice* aspect on the scene itself, allowing them to invoke it regularly around enemies near the river. They might have some free invocations on it to spend as a result of their Create Advantage action. However, the enemies might also invoke this one against them, too.
- Place an aspect like *Slipping on Ice* or *On Slippery Ice* on a single enemy (everyone else will be unaffected). This now inherently means that enemy is busy *Slipping on Ice* or *On Slippery Ice*, and they'll have to Overcome that aspect if they want to stop slipping around. This might even mean they can't leave the river until they Overcome it - they're too busy slipping around to get away!

  Your player may now invoke this aspect against that particular slipping enemy whenever they like, until it's Overcome.

  Of course, the slipping enemy could also invoke it themselves: suppose that enemy rolled poorly on their defence, and their attacker is at +1 on this attack. The enemy could invoke their *Slipping on Ice* aspect to say they suddenly slip over, surprisingly helping them avoid the attack - they get a +2 to their defence roll, and their attacker is now at -1 and might fail their attack roll.

Answer (score 11):

To answer the question you explicitly asked:

***You*** control what is hidden and what is not as the storyteller.

All aspects should be known except those you are specifically hiding, the [Fate Rules suggest there are a few ways to do this](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/using-aspects-roleplaying#secret-or-hidden-aspects), specifically:

> In those cases, it is recommended that you don’t make an aspect
>   directly out of whatever fact you’re trying to keep secret. Instead,
>   make the aspect a detail that makes sense in context after the secret
>   is revealed.
>
> *Amanda is making an NPC who’s secretly a vampire, the main bad guy in the scenario she’s planning. He’s also a constable in the town the PCs
>   are going to, so she doesn’t want to give things away too easily.*
>
> *Instead of making a Secretly a Vampire aspect, she decides to make a few personal details instead: Inveterate Night Owl, Tougher Than He
>   Looks, and Wheels Within Wheels. If the PCs discover a couple of
>   these, or see them on the table, they might start to suspect the NPC,
>   but it’s not going to ruin the mystery of the scenario right away.*

---

To address something you might be doing wrong:

You mentioned that one of the zones had a river, if you remember the rules about creating zones, you should give them each a [situation aspect](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/types-aspects#situation-aspects) or two:

> Physical features of the environment (Dense Underbrush, Obscuring
>   Snowdrifts, Low Gravity Planet)

So they should not have had to try to create an advantage to use the river, it should have already been there.

Answer (score 7):

## What Aspects Should Players Know?

Fred Hicks and Lenny Balsera (the guys behind the game) on the mailing lists have generally advocated the view that aspects should be known to the Players (not necessarily the characters) unless there is a compelling reason not to (such as giving away a plot point). The characters have knowledge of any aspects that are observable (such as, in most cases, a river).

Furthermore they have said that aspects are there to give a mechanical representation of narrative realities. The fact that there is a river present means there is a de facto aspect named **river**. To freeze the river the player just announces his character's intention and rolls.

## Creating Aspects

Now let's say you didn't put a river there but you don't really care whether one is present or not:

***Option A:*** Use [Create an Advantage](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/four-actions#create-an-advantage) to create an aspect.

> The Player announces "My character is looking for a source of water" and rolls Create an Advantage with his Notice. On a success there is now the aspect **River** on the scene which represents the fact that *yeah, there's a river right over there* and he has a free invoke on the aspect which he can use for a +2 on his next turn when he creates an aspect of **slippery ice**.

***Option B:*** Use a fate point to [declare a story detail](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/fate-point-economy#spending-fate-points).

> The player announces "By the way, I'm going to use the river that's been right here all along and freeze it" *while handing you a Fate Point*. He then proceeds to roll Create an Advantage of **slippery ice**

The difference between A, and B is that in B the player is indicating he really wants the river there and is willing to use some of his control over the story to ensure there is a river there. In A, he's willing to use a river *if one exists* but if not he'll think of something else.

## Discovering Aspects

Because a created aspect is true **retroactively**, they have intentionally left the lines between creating an aspect and discovering an aspect blurry. For instance, in Option A the player is *creating* the aspect, but the character is *discovering* it.

When the issue is a plot point, the rules suggest you create indirect aspects that hint at what you're trying to not say.

> In other words, the character who *is secretly a vampire* has aspects such as **night owl**, and **unnaturally tough**.

The benefit of doing so is that it  gives the characters clues to investigate further *(If he's a night owl, what does he do at night?)* while not spilling the beans precisely, it also gives the NPC aspects to invoke which are part of the nature you're trying to hide.

> Rather than invoke his **sneaky vampire** aspect when defending he can just invoke **unnaturally tough** and all the players will know it's because he's a actually a bloodsucking undead monster.

### How to make the Players discover aspects

Now we come to what to do when you want the players themselves to have to figure out what to look for and investigate. This will be mostly useful in mystery type stories.

The short answer is that you hold the cards with those aspects to yourself and the characters can do a Create an Advantage action when narratively they are looking for evidence of *(make them fill in the blank)*. If their roll succeeds, and what they are looking for is close enough to a *real* aspect the character has, then you reveal that aspect.

> For instance, the players decide to investigate a government official suspecting he is behind some missing money. They Create an Advantage on an aspect of **new and expensive buying habits** which the character doesn't have but he does have **recent large charity donations** so you reveal that instead since it's fairly similar.

Depending on the success of their dice roll you could let them discover aspects which are not so closely related, or give them a boost which represents someone they could ask about another matter.

Comment: I've added a couple of citations to the Fate SRD for Options A & B. For a minute I was confused as to why the player was handing the GM a fate point in option B - then I realised it was because of spending a fate point to declare a story detail. I think it's important to point to that mechanic so that people understand what's going on there. Good answer; +1